# How To Bind OpenVPN to ppp0 from Mobile Broadband?

Tags: openvpn

**My main question is:**

How to bind my ppp0 interface connection (from Mobile Broadband ZTE AC782) into my OpenVPN connection (from vpngate.net config file)?

**In short words:**

I want to hide my IP on all applications by VPN but I **only** can not do it if I connected via ppp0.

**My case is:**

- My IP address is still detected by http://whatismyip.com as my ISP's IP (Indonesia) not another country specified in config file after I start `sudo openvpn --config the_config_file.ovpn`.
- As a comparison, when I connect to the internet via wlan0 (any wifi hotspot), my command `sudo openvpn --config the_config_file.ovpn` **always** bind wlan0 interface and my IP address detected as another country according to the OpenVPN config file.
- In short, my OpenVPN can not "wrap" ppp0 interface.

**My workaround:**

- I read and tried what [this tutorial](https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/) explained. But my IP is still detected as my ISP's IP.
- I read and tried binding address by parameter -local from [this tutorial](https://serverfault.com/questions/596889/how-to-set-openvpn-client-bind-address), but it is same.
- I read and tried this tutorial to force any connection to whatismyip.com to pass through tun0, but bash says "**tun0: Unknown host**".

**My networking conditions:**

I connected into the internet via wvdial.

**ifconfig**

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:30204 (30.2 KB)  TX bytes:30204 (30.2 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.253.192.118  P-t-P:10.20.31.22  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18431 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:11671986 (11.6 MB)  TX bytes:2174511 (2.1 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.211.1.13  P-t-P:10.211.1.14  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:7270 (7.2 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**ip rule show**

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32764:  from all to 10.253.192.118 lookup admin 
32765:  from 10.253.192.118 lookup admin 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**ip route list**

```
default dev ppp0  scope link 
10.20.31.22 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.253.192.118 
10.211.1.14 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.211.1.13
```

**wvdial**:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT#777
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
CONNECT 3100000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat Jan 31 13:23:59 2015
--> Warning: Could not modify /etc/ppp/pap-secrets: Permission denied
--> --> PAP (Password Authentication Protocol) may be flaky.
--> Warning: Could not modify /etc/ppp/chap-secrets: Permission denied
--> --> CHAP (Challenge Handshake) may be flaky.
--> Pid of pppd: 4591
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> local  IP address 10.253.192.118
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> remote IP address 10.20.31.22
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> primary   DNS address 10.17.118.187
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
--> secondary DNS address 10.17.118.251
--> pppd: p8�[08]8@�[08]
```

Is there any workaround for to so my ppp0 connection can go trough VPN? What is the technique name of this problem? Routing? I am sorry I know nothing about networking. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any clue for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is how it worked on Kali linux guess it should work for you too:

CONNECT Your modem to the Internet first but don't connect Openvpn yet,

```
/sbin/ip addr show ppp0 | grep peer | awk ' { print $4 } ' | sed 's/\/32//'

ip route replace default via xx:xx:xx:xx dev ppp0
```

Replace xxxxx with your gateway displayed by the first code.

Solved [here](http://9jera.com/forums/topic/unable-to-redirect-default-gateway-cannot-read-current-default-gateway/)

Comment: It works perfectly. Yes I should connect my modem first.